# How to convert Mqtt5 payload back into JSON

Tags: java, arrays, json, mqtt, hivemq

How do I convert `Mqtt5Publish.getPayloadAsBytes()` into a properly formatted JSON string?

i.e.
Get a message published like this:

```
'{"SampleData0": "1.2.3", "SampleData1": "4.5.6"}'
```

Back into the same format when the subscriber obtains it.

I'm using the HiveMQTT Client Library in Java.

Comment: Why would you not just use the `.getPayloadAsBytes()` function?!?

`new String(incoming.getPayloadAsBytes())`

Comment: That is what I am using, edited the question to fix the typo. And to clarify that doesn't return a properly formatted JSON string from what i can tell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Issue was actually caused by some incorrect JSON formatting on the part of the publisher. The publisher client was sending the JSON as:

```
"{"SampleData0": "1.2.3", "SampleData1": "4.5.6"}"
```

However this meant that when my subscriber client received the payload and converted it from a byte array into a JSON String the payload would look like this:

```
{SampleData0: 1.2.3, SampleData1: 4.5.6}
```

To fix this I had the publisher client send:

```
'{"SampleData0": "1.2.3", "SampleData1": "4.5.6"}'
```

Notice the use of single quote, `'`, chars rather than double, this escapes the double quote characters, `"`, so that they remain present when the byte array is converted back into a JSON, giving this properly formatted JSON string when using `new String(mqtt5Publish.getPayloadAsBytes())`

```
{"SampleData0": "1.2.3", "SampleData1": "4.5.6"}
```